# Should I use one `hsm_secret` for both the mainnet and the testnet?

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, mnemonic-seed, backup, core-lightning

When I launch `lightningd` it generates `hsm_secret` in `~/.lightning/bitcoin`
whereas launching `lightningd` with `network=testnet` generates `hsm_secret` in `~/.lightning/testnet`.
These two files seem to be different as confirmed by

```
diff ~/.lightning/bitcoin/hsm_secret ~/.lightning/testnet/hsm_secret
```

returning some output.

Having in mind that `hsm_secret` may get corrupted and being concerned with the security of my funds I decided to generate `hsm_secret` from BIP-39 words
and back up both the phrase and the file.
After compiling **[c-lightning](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning)** from source and generating [the mnemonic with [Python](https://github.com/trezor/python-mnemonic), I then [followed the documentation](https://lightning.readthedocs.io/BACKUP.html) and run:

```
~/lightning/tools/lightning-hsmtool generatehsm hsm_secret
```

It generated `hsm_secret` in the current directory.
After trying `~/lightning/tools/lightning-hsmtool generatehsm hsm_secret testnet` and finding out that it does not work I decided
to try using the same `hsm_secret` file for both the testnet and the mainnet, i.e. I
launched `lightningd` with `network=testnet` and replaced the auto-generated `hsm_secret` in
`~/.lightning/testnet` with the one I generated from my mnemonic and than did the same with `network=bitcoin` and `~/.lightning/bitcoin/hsm_secret`. I was surprized to see that all seems to work fine,
e.g. `newaddr` generates tb1 addresses when on testnet and bc1 addresses when on mainnet.

What are the pros and cons of using the seperate `hsm_secret` files vs using only one file for both networks.?